# GFS SIG/SFC file format of siganl.gdas/sfcanl.gdas analyzing/decoding problem

Tags: raster, file-formats

I am creating a database from datafiles. I encountered many fails and errors, which I have already fixed (also with the help of this Q&A web). Now I am stucked a bit in decoding of 6 files because I totally don't know in what format they are coded.

Those files are:

```
sigf06.gdas.2010123100
sigf00.gdas.2010123100
siganl.gdas.2010123100

sfcf06.gdas.2010123100
sfcf00.gdas.2010123100
sfcanl.gdas.2010123100
```

They are binary and when I open them in hexa (in console with od -c "filename"), I see the first 3 files have

> "\0  \0  \0       G   F   S       S   I   G      \0 003 017   ="

on the first line and the next 3 files have

> "\0  \0  \0       G   F   S       S   F   C      \0 003 017   ="

on the first line and after that all those 6 files have binary data.

All I know is that I downloaded them from directory 
http://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/modeldata/cmd_HIC/2010/201012/20101231/ (any of the 4 .tar.gz files) 
and the link to this directory I have from 
http://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data.php#CFSR-data -> High Resolution Initial Conditions HTTP link. 
All the datafiles contain geo data in a grid, I think that those 6 files store land values. 
First 3 files have 227MB, the other 3 files have 117MB.

I am already quite insane how non-documented the files are, but it's still the best source for the needed data to my database. 
There is probably some documentation of the files, but I haven't found any. There was about 20 dataset files in those .tar.gzs, the majority I already decoded. If I knew just the format of these files, I would convert them easily, but link to the documentation of these files with structure and filetypes would be the best.